# Timestamp Maths, percentages

Tags: php, math, timestamp, percentage

I'm trying to work out a simple algorithm to get a percentage of how far the current time is, in-between two timestamps. (this is confusing to write so probably confusing to read, sorry)

I'm using PHP and Unix timestamps "time()"

So far I've got,

```
$percentCompleted = ((time() - $startTimestamp) / $endTimestamp) * 100;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How you define `$endTimestamp`? Is it a timestamp? I think it should be estimated duration

Comment: $endTimestamp is worked out by time() + $secondsUntilExpire

Comment: So you don't need `$endTimestamp` in expression. Use `$secondsUntilExpire` instead: `$percentCompleted = ((time() - $startTimestamp) / $secondsUntilExpire) * 100;`

Comment: $endTimestamp is recorded and pulled from a database for this.

Comment: And what? What is the reason to use `$endTimestamp`?

Comment: Have a start and finish, need to find the point in-between as a percentage. Therefore,  it'd need STARTSTAMP -----> ENDSTAMP.

Comment: `$percentCompleted = ((time() - $startTimestamp) / ($endTimestamp - $startTimestamp)) * 100;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need normalize result by difference from start timestamp to end timestamp.

```
$percentCompleted = ((time() - $startTimestamp) / ($endTimestamp - $startTimestamp)) * 100;
```

Of course you can add some protecting against invalid input like time() > $endTimestamp

```
$percentCompleted = ((min(time(),$endTimestamp)  - $startTimestamp) / ($endTimestamp - $startTimestamp)) * 100;
```

Comment: This seems to work but a few results came back with a negative percentage. I'll investigate.

Comment: @McDanGarrett it is probably caused by time()<$startTimestamp.